# reserved view name in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a view name 06012016 after today's date in MMddyyyy format.
Visual studio will not let me create it. I get the following error message "View name is invalid because it is reserved"
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWyxo.jpg)

anyone know why?

Comment: A view gets converted to a class, a class name cannot begin with a number.

Comment: I could able to add, which version of VS are you using?